# ios - Font Awesome Icon Not Working With UIButton IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, font-awesome

I'm trying to implement FontAwesome's icons in my Xcode Project. I have put in the `fontawesome.ttf` file into my project, and I am using code from this github to put them into the `UIImageView` of my `UIButton`: https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome.

I am able to get the icons into my app by doing this sample code from the github Demo here:

```
FAImageView *imageView = [[FAImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 100.f, 100.f)];
    imageView.image = nil;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageWithIcon:@"fa-github" backgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor] iconColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:255] fontSize:50];
    UIImageView *github = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:icon];
    CGRect rect = github.frame;
    rect.origin.y += CGRectGetMaxY(imageView.frame);
    github.frame = rect;
    [self.view addSubview:github];
```

However, I'm trying to put a FontAwesome icon in a `UIButton`'s image view (which is in the storyboard connected to an `IBOutlet`) with this code:

```
self.backOneSentenceButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithIcon:@"fa-backward" backgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor] iconColor:[UIColor blackColor] andSize:self.backOneSentenceButton.bounds.size];
```

But the icon isn't showing up at all in the button, and it's just a plain white button. Is there anything I might be missing here? Or am I doing it completely wrong? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just set class of image as your lib you have added.

[image]

Hope this could help.